# Reduction of sample space and conditional probability formula

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In conditional probability, we find the occurrence of an event given that another event has already occurred. So the formula of P(A|B) = P(intersection of A and B) over P(B).

My doubt is, if event B *has already occurred* , it would mean that our reduced sample space is the entire set of B. So shouldn't P(B) = 1 just like how we say P(S) = 1 where S is the sample space?

Answer (score 2):

What you are thinking of is that it is certain that $B$ occurs *when given that* $B$ occurs.$$\mathsf P(B\mid B)=1$$

That says nothing about the *unconditional* probability that $B$ occurs (ie: when it is *not given*).

---

What is the probability that event $A$ occurs when given that event $B$ occurs?   It is the weighted measure of outcomes in event $A$ that occur within the event of $B$.   Thus, it is the measure of the intersection, $A\cap B$, divided by the measure of $B$.$$\mathsf P(A\mid B)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$

---

For example:  The roll of standard six-sided dice consists of six equally probable events $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Let $B$ be the event of rolling an even number on a standard six sided dice.   This event consists of the three equally probable outcomes, $B=\{2,4,6\}$, so we claim the probability of this event is $1/2$.$$\mathsf P(B)=1/2$$

Let $A$ be the event of rolling a prime number.   There is only one outcome among the three equally probable outcomes of event $B$ that is also an outcome of event $A$; ie $A\cap B=\{2\}$.

Hence the conditional probability for $A$ when given $B$ is $1/3$.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{1/6}{1/2}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac 13\end{align}$$

Comment: Why do we worry about the unconditional probability of B? We've already established that event B occurs, so P(B) should be 1 right

Comment: No, we haven't established that $B$ does occur; we are measuring the probability for $A$ occurring *if* $B$ occurs.  @noorav

Comment: Oh. I thought we establish B has occurred because it's a "given"